# Short if-else statements in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable called **$day_price** that can hold one of two values - either "**weekday_price**" or "**weekend_price**". If I'm echoing **$day_price** however I would like the value of **weekday_price** to be echoed as **Weekday Price** and the value of **weekend_price** to be echoed as **Weekend Price**.

How can I achieve this without writing a long if-else statement like this?

```
if ($day_price=="weekday_price") { 
    echo "Weekday Price";
}
else if ($day_price=="weekend_price") { 
    echo "Weekend Price";
}
```

Comment: Just because this has not been shown: `echo GetPriceTitle($day_price);` (Then it really doesn't matter how.)

Comment: I would suggest a new title for posterity Google searches, but I can't think of a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without conditions:

```
$res = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $day_price));
```

For more information see [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct way (this is a "problem" for all programming languages).

You can, for example, build an array with key value pairs where key is weekend_price and value is Weekend Price

```
$tmpArray = array(
    "weekend_price" => "Weekend Price",
    "weekday_price" => "Weekday Price"
);
echo $tmpArray[$day_price];
```

Otherwise if you are sure you'll use "_" instead of spaces, and you want uppercase all words, you can use this:

```
echo ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $day_price));
```

Another solution (which I don't like but can be used):

```
function ConvertWeekPrices($day_price)
{
    $result = null;
    switch($day_price)
    {
        case "weekend_price":
            $result = "Weekend Price";
            break;
        case "weekday_price":
            $result = "Weekday Price";
            break;
    }
    // Do something with result if you want
    // Do some checks if result is null
    return $result;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
echo ConvertWeekPrices($day_price);
```

There are other approaches, you can use a database table, an xml file, there are unlimited combinations. I think those 2 are the easier approaches

Answer (score 2):

A literal answer would be

```
$trans = array (
  "weekday_price" => "Weekday Price",
  "weekend_price" => "Weekend Price",
);
echo $trans[$day_price];
```

however, there is a way to avoid such a translation, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $date_check ) );
```

See [ucwords in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in different places, you could define an associative array:

```
$texts = array('weekday_price' => 'Weekday Price',
               'weekend_price' => 'Weekend Price');
```

And use that like:

```
echo $texts[$day_price];
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only ever going to be weekend or weekday you could do:

```
echo ($day_price=="weekday_price") ? 'Weekday Price' : 'Weekend Price';
```

But i'd be careful when exchanging readability (therefore maintainability) for a few saved lines of code.